# How can i exception handle through a lambda function? [tkinter]

Tags: tkinter, exception, messagebox

College student.
I have a bit of code here, but  i can't seem to retrieve the .get() user Entries from the lambda function.
As a result, i can't do any exception handling. The only catch i could manage was checking to make sure there was no repeat usernames in the database.  I tried returning the .get() variables to the function, but to no avail.  Here is the snippet of the code i am referring to:

```
def second_win():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Please enter your personal details")
    window.geometry('500x500')
    Label(window, text = 'Create Username').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    Label(window, text=" First Name").grid(row=1, column = 0 )
    Label(window, text=" Last Name").grid(row=2,column = 0)
    Label(window, text = "Age").grid(row = 3,column = 0)
    Label(window, text = "Height (m)").grid(row = 4,column = 0)
    Label(window, text = "Weight(kg)").grid(row = 5,column = 0)
    UserName = Entry(window, width = 25)
    UserName.grid(row = 0, column =1)
    User_FirstName = Entry(window, width = 25)
    User_FirstName.grid(row=1, column = 1)
    User_Surname = Entry(window, width = 25)
    User_Surname.grid(row=2, column = 1 )
    User_Age = Entry(window, width = 25)
    User_Age.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    User_Height = Entry(window, width = 25)
    User_Height.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    User_Weight = Entry(window, width = 25)
    User_Weight.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
    Button(window, text='Quit', command=window.quit).grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W, padx = 100,  pady=100)
    Button(window, text='Submit', command= lambda: submit_details([ UserName.get(), User_FirstName.get(), User_Surname.get(), User_Age.get(), User_Height.get(),User_Weight.get()])).grid()

def submit_details(details):
    user_name_list = cursor.execute(''' SELECT UserName FROM GetUserDataInput''')
    if details[0] in [username[0] for username in user_name_list]:
       messagebox.showerror("Error", "User Already Exists")


    else:
        sql = '''INSERT INTO GetUserDataInput(UserName, FirstName, LastName, Age, Height, Weight)
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
        cursor.execute(sql, details)
```

Here, sql is just a class with some methods relating to a database, such as: creating connection, cursor and query. I have not put it here in case it is redundant, but will happily drop it where needed.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to not use lambda. Create a proper function, and it will be easier to write, easier to understand, and easier to debug. In this specific case, `lambda` is doing nothing but making your code more complicated than it needs to be.

In this specific case, just move the calls to `get` inside of the `submit_details` function.

```
def second_win():
    ...
    Button(window, text='Submit', command= submit_details).grid()
    ...

def submit_details():
    username = UserName.get()
    firstname = User_FirstName.get()
    surname = User_Surname.get()
    age = User_Age.get()
    height = User_Height.get()
    weight = User_weight.get()
    ...
```

If you prefer to leave `submit_details` the way that it is, create an intermediate function to get the data from the UI before passing it to `submit_details`:

```
def second_win():
    ...
    Button(window, text='Submit', command=submit).grid()
    ...

def submit():
    username = UserName.get()
    firstname = User_FirstName.get()
    surname = User_Surname.get()
    age = User_Age.get()
    height = User_Height.get()
    weight = User_weight.get()
    
    data = [username, firstname, surname, age, height, weight]
    submit_details(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the second function, def submit() containing the username.get()... methods are all 'unresolved references'

Comment: @superbo9y: yes, you're right. I wasn't thinking. I'm so used to using classes that I forgot to realize you're using local variables. You can move `submit` as a nested function, or better, convert `second_win` to a class.

Comment: edit: i created an inner function, using the same format as above, and it seems to be working now. Creating an intermediate function is class